# TableView with observablelist now showing data - javafx

Tags: javafx

I have this simple tableView designed in Scene builder. I have a button that I press, that's supposed to add the data from the ObservableList to the table, but the data doesnt appear. The table changes from "no data" to a scrollable table with no data inside it.

Code:

```
@FXML private TableView<Record> tableView;
static ObservableList<Record> dataen =
      FXCollections.observableArrayList(          
          new Record("January", 100),
          new Record("February", 200));
```

To set the data:

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
      tableView.setItems(dataen);
     }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you haven't specified any TableColumns or CellValueFactories for each of your columns. See the JavaDoc for TableView.

Comment: Do you have to do this even though you are using scene builder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you haven't specified any TableColumns or CellValueFactories for each of your columns. See the JavaDoc for TableView.

You can add the TableColumns in SceneBuilder, and assign each an fx:id
Then in your initialize method add for eg:

```
monthCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("monthName"));
```

where monthName is referring to a method `monthNameProperty()` in your Record class.

Comment: You can set the cellValueFactory in FXML too, if you prefer, though I don't see a way to do this in SceneBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the code underneath to the intialize method. I didnt beleive I had to do this when I used Scene Builder, turns out I were wrong?

```
Month.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fieldMonth"));
Value.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fieldValue"));

tableView.setItems(dataen);
```